# localhost redirected you too many times. - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting this error all the time.  Can't figure out what the problem is. I tried clearing my cookies / the entire browsing history still no luck.

In my index.aspx i have the code below on page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        { 
             Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, true);
        }   
    }
```

In the web config I have this :

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="app_files/home.aspx" loginUrl="index.aspx" name="osivms" path="/" protection="All" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="525600" />
    </authentication>
```

Sometimes It does work though.. but its really random and I dont know what changed when it works.. then after I hit refresh or something I get the same error message again...

Comment: That's really not enough information. Where does `Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, true);` take you?

Comment: to : app_files/home.aspx

Comment: And where is the c# code you posted?

Comment: everytime your index page is loaded, you are trying to authenticate..What does your app_files/home.aspx page do? Could it be redirecting back to your index.aspx ergo your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed. I followed the instructions on this [page](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates) and my localhost is back working now.

I had to delete the old certificate and create a self signed new certificate and bind it to the site.